# window size when switching from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having a problem when switching to a vertical screen, specifically the LazyHorizontalGrid is forced to equal the screen height when the screen is horizontal.when the screen is horizontal it looks like the layout is pressed for the full screen height.When you use a Scaffold in the portrait version, it also helps you set the content color to the background color. To set the color of the Navigation Strip, wrap it in a Surface and set it to background color.You have a Landscape Preview that looks pretty good. However, if you run an app on a device or emulator and then rotate to the side, it won't show the landscape version to you. That's because we need to tell the application when it will show its configuration. To do this, use the function to see what configuration the phone is in.

biểu đồ kích thước cửa sổ

There are 3 window size class widths: Compact, Medium and Extended. When in portrait mode, the app has a Compact width, while when in landscape mode, the app has an Extended width. Within the scope of this programming class, you won't be working with Medium Width.

Under MySootheApp Matching Component, update to get in your device's WindowSizeClass. If the width is compact, pass the vertical version of the application. If it's landscape mode, cast the landscape version of the app.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val windowSizeClass = calculateWindowSizeClass(this)
            MySootheApp(windowSizeClass)
        }
    }
}

// Step: Align your body row - Arrangements
@Composable
fun AlignYourBodyRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    LazyRow(
        modifier = modifier,
        contentPadding= PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        items(alignYourBodyData) { item ->
            AlignYourBodyElement(item.drawable, item.text)
        }
    }
}

// Step: Favorite collections grid - LazyGrid
@Composable
fun FavoriteCollectionsGrid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    LazyHorizontalGrid(
        rows = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement=Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement=Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        modifier = modifier.height(168.dp)
    ) {
        items(favoriteCollectionsData) { item ->
            FavoriteCollectionCard(item.drawable, item.text)
        }
    }
}

// Step: Home section - Slot APIs
@Composable
fun HomeSection(
    @StringRes title: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Column(modifier) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(title),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
            modifier = Modifier
                .paddingFromBaseline(top = 40.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        )
        content()
    }
}

// Step: Home screen - Scrolling
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(modifier) {
        Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
        SearchBar(Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp))
        HomeSection(title = R.string.align_your_body) {
            AlignYourBodyRow()
        }
        HomeSection(title = R.string.favorite_collections) {
            FavoriteCollectionsGrid()
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))

    }
}

fun MySootheAppLandscape() {
    MySootheTheme {
        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
            Row {
                SootheNavigationRail()
                HomeScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What if the screen is horizontal but the LazyHorizontalGrid has the same width as the vertical screen

[image]
I want the LazyHorizontalGrid not to be forced when the screen is turned off

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.